# How many $(r+1)$- subsets of $[n+1]$ have $(k+1)$ as their largest element?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, permutations, binomial-theorem

Let $[n+1]$ be the set defined by $[n+1]=\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$.

Call a subset of $[n+1]$ with $r+1$ distinct elements an $(r+1)$-subset. How many $(r+1)$-subsets of $[n+1]$ have $(k+1)$ as their largest element?

---

This seem fairly facile, so I am concerned that I am doing it wrong. By definition, $[n+1]$ is a bounded set. If $(r+1)$ is a subset of $[n+1]$, then $(r+1)$ is bounded as well. Denote that bound as $k+1$ s.t. $k \geq r_0 \forall r_0 \in (r+1)$.

Is anything wrong here?

Additionally, I am supposed to deduce that

$$\sum^n_{k=r}{k\choose r}={n+1\choose r+1}.$$

I have no idea where to start for this one.

**EDIT:** Using the hints given by Hagen von Eitzen, I claim that the total number of subsets of $[n+1]$ that have $(k+1)$ as their largest element is $k$. Note that an $(r+1)$-element subset of $[n+1]$ is an $(r+1)$-element subset of $[n+1]$ that has $k+1$ as maximal elelment for exactly one k∈{r,…,n}.

I am fairly sure that I can prove this by induction. Can someone suggest anything for the second half and whether I did the first half correctly?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If you remove the known element $k+1$ from such a subset it becomes an arbitrary $r$-element subset of $[k]$.

**Second Hint:** An $(r+1)$-element subset of $[n+1]$ is an $(r+1)$-element subset of $[n+1]$ that has $k+1$ as maximal elelment for exactly one $k\in\{r,\ldots,n\}$.